# Error in loading RWeka

Tags: r, rweka

After installing the RWeka package with R studio,

```
library(RWeka)
```

produces a fatal error, forcing me to start a new session.

loading the package in R vanilla shows an error message like this.

```
> library(RWeka)

*** caught segfault ***
address 0xbf913, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .jinit()
 2: .jpackage(pkgname, lib.loc = libname)
 3: fun(libname, pkgname)
 4: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 5: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 6: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 7: tryCatch(fun(libname, pkgname), error = identity)
 8: runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package)
 9: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
10: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),         versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
11: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
12: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
13: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
14: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
15: tryCatch({    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)}, error = function(e) {    P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e)))         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])    else ""    msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s",         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))    if (logical.return)         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)    else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)})
16: library(RWeka)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

I'm currently using Java Version 8 Update 181, R version 3.5.0, and R Studio 1.1.423 on macOD High Sierra (version 10.13.5).

Is there a way to work this through?

Comment: You do not mention that you have installed the Weka package. Did you realize that RWeka was only an interface to an external package? (The package description is clear about this. On mine its package Description entry says: "An R interface to Weka (Version 3.9.2)." That said, it's always an error that should be reported to the package maintainer when you get a segfault, and the same file say  `Maintainer: Kurt Hornik <Kurt.Hornik@R-project.org>`

Comment: Still doesn't work after installing the Weka package. This means I should report to the package manager?

Comment: Not necessarily. It means you should use the SO [edit] facilities to describe in excruciating detail everything you have done, what instructions you were following for the installation of Weka, and all your version numbers for the interlcking pieces, and what your environment variables are, and what error messages you are now getting (which I suspect are now different).